# bind data to checkboxlist

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to bind data to checkboxlist and am getting the below Error:

> Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource,
>   IEnumerable, or IDataSource.

The Code i am using is:

```
for(var day = fromdate; day.Date <= todate; day = day.AddDays(1))
{
    LeaveDtl.DataSource = day;
    LeaveDtl.DataBind ();
}
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. First you are binding data in a loop so only the last item will actually be visible. Second as the error message states you can only bind certain types, and a `DateTime` is not one of them

Comment: Hi James,
I want to send staring date & end Date as parameters for a checkboxlist. All the dates ranging between the dates to be displayed in checkboxlist for user to select/check the dates based on his requirement.
Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add individual items in a loop, do it like this:

```
for (var day = fromdate; day.Date <= todate; day = day.AddDays(1))
{
    LeaveDtl.Items.Insert(LeaveDtl.Items.Count, new ListItem(day.ToShortDateString(), day.ToShortDateString()));
}
```